# Datatables initialization warning

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a dropdown with multiple options that initializes a datatable using javascript. Everything works fine but the problem comes during execution in which when the option is selected second time i get an error , check out this [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/bobin56/et9rdg44/),

```
DataTables warning (table id = 'defDiv'): Cannot reinitialise DataTable.
```

And Below is my code :

```
   if(user.position=="DEF"){
var table = $('#defDiv').DataTable({
    "aaData":defenders,
     "iDisplayLength":15,
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mDataProp": "playerInfo" },
        { "mDataProp": "playerName" },
          { "mDataProp": "playerClub" },
        { "mDataProp": "playerValue" },
         { "mDataProp": "playerPoints" },
    ],
     "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]],
  });
}
```

Question is how can i prevent the warning from happening when the option is selected again ?

Comment: @davidkonrad it's my mistake. use "bDestroy" : true and i delete my comment also

Comment: I notice that the table ID given in your error message differs from your code - may be worth looking into.

Comment: @Ash , the IDs matches , i forgot to change it when question was asked..

Comment: @davidkonrad, please check this [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/bobin56/et9rdg44/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've altered you code and it works now:

```
var goalkepeers = [{
    "playerName": "Mignolet",
    "playerClub": "Liverpool",
    "playerValue": "5.0",
    "playerPoints": "89",
}, {
    "playerName": "de Gea",
    "playerClub": "Manchester",
    "playerValue": "6.7",
    "playerPoints": "120",
}];
var defenders = [{
    "playerName": "Ivanovic",
    "playerClub": "Chelsea",
    "playerValue": "7.8",
    "playerPoints": "100",
}, {
    "playerName": "Mertesacker",
    "playerClub": "Arsenal",
    "playerValue": "7.7",
    "playerPoints": "110",
}];
var aoColumns = [{
    "sTitle": "Name", 
    "mDataProp": "playerName"
},{
    "sTitle": "Club", 
    "mDataProp": "playerClub"
},{
    "sTitle": "Value", 
    "mDataProp": "playerValue"
},{
    "sTitle": "Points", 
    "mDataProp": "playerPoints"
}];
var table = null;
$("#playersFilter").change(function () {
    var value = $('#playersFilter').val();
    if (value == "gk") {
        if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#players')) {
            $('#players').DataTable().destroy();
        } 
        table = $('#players').DataTable({
            "aaData": goalkepeers,
            "iDisplayLength": 15,
            "aoColumns": aoColumns,
            "bRetrieve": true,
            "order": [
                [3, "desc"]
            ],
            "bDestroy": true
        });
    } else if (value == "def") {
        if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#players')) {
            $('#players').DataTable().destroy();
        }
        table = $('#players').DataTable({
            "aaData": defenders,
            "iDisplayLength": 15,
            "aoColumns": aoColumns,
            "bRetrieve": true,
            "order": [
                [3, "desc"]
            ],
            "bDestroy": true,
        });
    }
});
```

I'm pretty sure there's a more efficient way of doing it, I'll have a think and post a link to a JSFiddle as a comment.

You only really need the one table as well:

```
<select id="playersFilter">
    <option>Choose Players</option>
    <option value="gk">goalkepeers</option>
    <option value="def">Defenders</option>
</select>
<table class="display" id="players"></table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  :-) if you find a simpler way please share it with me :-)

Comment: Updated the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ux7weoto/) with more elegant code. Basically initialised the datatable and clear and add rows (or not) as a result of the change event.

Comment: Thanks again :-) but one quick question if you don't mind , what will i do if i want to display goalkeper and defenders from the same team ? like imagine adding another option for club.

Comment: Concatenate the arrays and add them, check the updated fiddle. though you should already have clocked that `rows().add()` is simply adding an array, if you want the array to include 2 or more then the arrays need to added to each other.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
if(user.position=="DEF"){
var table = $('#defDiv').DataTable({
    "aaData":defenders,
     "iDisplayLength":15,
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mDataProp": "playerInfo" },
        { "mDataProp": "playerName" },
          { "mDataProp": "playerClub" },
        { "mDataProp": "playerValue" },
         { "mDataProp": "playerPoints" },
    ],
```

**//EDITS**

```
     "bRetrieve":true,
     "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]],
       // use this in your code

      "bDestroy": true,
  });
}
```

this will work for me & 
[more details](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/6261/how-to-reinitialize-a-datatable)

Comment: Thanks for helping but the bDestroy only removes the warning but does not show the table when an option  is selected again .

Comment: @bobin56 use "bRetrieve": true use for retrieve the table

Comment: do you  mind if you could explain where i should put that line of code since the destroy and retrival should be done in the same if statement, thanks again :-)

Comment: @bobin56 update my answer please check. if it's not working please inform

Comment: It does not work , still same response , warning gone but datatable not loaded ....can u   please try the codes for me , Thanks again :-)

Comment: @bobin56 just create your table as global and append table id not div id

Comment: Hi , please find this working  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bobin56/et9rdg44/) , it shows excactly your approach . can you please edit it so as the values dont dissapear on second selection

Answer (score 0):

Can you just `destroy` the table prior to re-initialization?

```
table.DataTable().destroy();
```

Something like this:

```js
var table;

if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#defDiv')) {
  table.DataTable().destroy();
} 
   
table = $('#defDiv').DataTable({...
```

Documentation can be found [here](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3)

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ze0erxxs/)

Comment: Hello Ash , Thanks for helping but table destroy removes the warning but it did not display my table values again when an option is selected the second time....

Comment: Try replacing table.destroy(); with table.DataTable().destroy(); I have updated my answer accordingly, and added a link to a (simplified) jsfiddle. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi , please check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bobin56/et9rdg44/) and  you will understand what went wrong . please make necessary edits , thanks again :-)